# Show full section titles in beamerarticle ToC when short section titles are present

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, sectioning, themes, beamerarticle

I am creating lecture notes and slides simultaneously using **beamerarticle**. In  **beamer**, I'm using a theme called Berlin which puts all section titles in the slide header. Because some section titles are long and don't fit, I have specified short titles such as:

```
\section[short title 1]{First Section's Full Title}
```

The short titles now appear in the slide header. However, this has an undesirable effect on the **article**: by default the short section titles now show up in the article's table of contents.

I read [this](http://wjsullivan.net/NotesLaTeX.html), and so tried using \sectionmark instead as follows:

```
\section{First Section's Full Title}
\sectionmark{short title 1}
```

However, **beamer** does not recognize sectionmark and now reverts to putting the full section titles in the slide header.

It seems to me that I need to somehow edit the default options of either the table of contents in the documentclass article, or the Berlin theme in beamer. Unfortunately I am quite new to LaTeX and have no idea how to do either. Help appreciated.

Among the packages I am using are titlesec and tocloft, but my problem occurs regardless of whether the packages are in use, thus I have commented them out in the minimal working example below. The code for the m.w.e. needs to be saved as **three separate tex files** in the same folder, as specified below. **Compile example.article.tex and example.beamer.tex, not example.tex**

```
%NOTE: The following should be saved as example.article.tex:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\input{example.tex}

%NOTE: The following should be saved as example.beamer.tex:
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
\input{example.tex} 

%NOTE: The following should be saved as example.tex:
%\mode<article>{
% \usepackage{tocloft}
% \usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
%}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Berlin}}
% everyone:
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
  \title{Title}
  \maketitle
 \end{frame}
 \begin{frame}{\only<presentation>{Outline}}
  \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
  \tableofcontents
 \end{frame}
 \section[short title 1]{First Section's Full Title}
 %\sectionmark{short title 1}
 \begin{frame}{First Frame}
  Blah blah text
 \end{frame}
 \begin{frame}{Second Frame}
  Blah blah text 2
 \end{frame}
 \section[short title 2]{Second Section's Full Title}
 %\sectionmark{short title 2}
 \begin{frame}{Third Frame}
  Blah blah text 3
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution is to use modes and to define a command `\Section` with tow arguments: one (the first one) optional argument will hold the short title for the navigation bar in `presentation` mode and the second, mandatory argument, will hold the title for the section both in `presentation` and in `article` modes. A complete example follows.

Processing the following test document:

```
    %\documentclass{article}
    \documentclass{beamer}
    %\usepackage{beamerarticle}


    \newcommand\Section[2][]{%
      \section<presentation>[#1]{#2}
      \section<article>{#2}
    }
    \usetheme{Berlin}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
    \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}
    \Section[Short title 1]{First Section's Full Title}
    \begin{frame}
    test
    \end{frame}

    \end{document}
```

produces the following frame (short tile in the navigation bar, full title in the ToC):

[image]

Now, using the article version:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}


\newcommand\Section[2][]{%
  \section<presentation>[#1]{#2}
  \section<article>{#2}
}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\Section[Short title 1]{First Section's Full Title}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

we receive the following ToC (full title in the ToC):

[image]

Comment: Dear Gonzalo, this worked for me - thanks a lot.

Comment: This solution worked for me. However just a note for future users who may use it:

We have to remove the optional `[ignorenonframetext]` argument in `\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}` for beamer to recognize `\Section` calls (which come outside of frame) - otherwise no headers or ToC will appear in beamer. So now any text between frames will appear on slides. But this is easily solved - text can be allocated to the article only by placing it within `\only<article>{}`

Comment: @ThomasFarrar I am glad to hear my solution worked for you. Please consider accepting the answer (up-voting and accepting are two different actions); in case of doubt please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Answer (score 2):

The `koma` classes have the option `headings=optiontohead`. By using this you can have the long section names to appear in the toc:

```
\documentclass[headings=optiontohead]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Berlin}}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\author{sd}

\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
  \title{Title}
  \maketitle
 \end{frame}
 \begin{frame}{\only<presentation>{Outline}}
  \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
  \tableofcontents
 \end{frame}
 \section[short title 1]{First Section's Full Title}
 %\sectionmark{short title 1}
 \begin{frame}{First Frame}
  Blah blah text
 \end{frame}
 \begin{frame}{Second Frame}
  Blah blah text 2
 \end{frame}
 \section[short title 2]{Second Section's Full Title}
 %\sectionmark{short title 2}
 \begin{frame}{Third Frame}
  Blah blah text 3
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The idea of Gonzalo Medina is genius but still not mature enough. It needs modification of your existing presentation to use `\Section` instead of the standard `\section`. The following code worked perfectly with me. It redefines the `\section` and the dependant `\section*` commands. You should put this code in the preamble of a `beamerarticle` document, so no need for mode specification using neither  nor . Thanks for Gonzalo Medina's post above, and [Christian Hupfer's post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211249/43713) for inspiring me the following code. You can extend this code for `\part`, `\subsection` and `\subsubsection` as well.

This also answers [this related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239891/show-full-section-titles-in-beamerarticle-toc-when-short-section-titles-are-pres).

```
\makeatletter
\let\OriginalSection\section
\newcommand{\starredsection}[1]{%
\OriginalSection*{#1}%
}

\newcommand\unstarredsection[2][]{%
\OriginalSection{#2}
}

\renewcommand{\section}{%
\@ifstar{\starredsection}{\unstarredsection}%
}%
\makeatother
```