# Using titlesec in beamerarticle with a modified section command

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, titlesec, beamerarticle

This is further to the solution provided to [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83650/show-full-section-titles-in-beamerarticle-toc-when-short-section-titles-are-pres) about allocating short and long titles correctly to the beamer and article output of a **beamerarticle**.

The solution provided there works fine; however it creates a further problem because I am also using the **titlesec** package to modify section title formatting in the article.

**titlesec** is designed for `\section` and, having used the solution in the previous question I am now using a customized command `\Section`. Any idea how to make **titlesec** "understand" `\Section`?

Additions to code for the minimal working example in the previous question:

```
\mode<article>{ 
 \usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
}

\only<article>{
 \titleformat{\section}
 {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
 \titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{2em}{0.5em}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can load `titlesec` and make the changes to the section style before loading `beamerarticle`.  Here is an example with a distinctively different title style:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\scshape}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{2em}{0.5em}

\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\newcommand\Section[2][]{%
\section<presentation>[#1]{#2}
\section<article>{#2}
}

\usetheme{Berlin}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\Section[Short title 1]{First Section's Full Title}
\begin{frame}
  test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

This code should be commented out if you run in beamer mode.  Alternatively, put the different preambles in different files, the body and common code in e.g. `main.tex` and use `\input{main.tex}` as suggested in the beamer documetation.

As far as I can tell, `titlesec` doesn't tolerate being loaded after `beamerarticle`.