# Show full section titles in beamerarticle ToC when short section titles are present-Continued

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, beamerarticle

This is a continuation of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83650/show-full-section-titles-in-beamerarticle-toc-when-short-section-titles-are-pres). I'm sorry, I couldn't add a comment there, so I wrote this new question. Gonzalo Medina solved the problem by defining a new `\Section` command. This cannot work with me. I'm using Lyx to create my beamer presentation and articles. So, I cannot tell Lyx to use the new defined `\Section` instead of the standard `\section` command.

So is there a way to redefine/patch either of the `\section` command or the toc so that the beamer-article toc uses section full title instead of the short title?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A small suggestion: You are not forced to use LyX to compile a document. ;-) In addition, I think other code can be added to the preamble even in a LyX environment such that it comes into action

Comment: Of course I don't have to use Lyx, but It is much more easier to use it. Please tell me what should I put in the preamble to solve my problem

Comment: I could find a solution for this question. So I'm [citing it on the original question page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/273279/43713).

Answer (score 1):

I could find a solution for this question. So I'm [citing it on the original question page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/273279/43713).

The following code worked perfectly with me. It redefines the `\section` and the dependant `\section*` commands. You should put this code in the preamble of a `beamerarticle` document, so no need for mode specification using neither  nor . Thanks for Gonzalo Medina's post above, and [Christian Hupfer's post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211249/43713) for inspiring me the following code. You can extend this code for `\part`, `\subsection` and `\subsubsection` as well.

```
\makeatletter
\let\OriginalSection\section
\newcommand{\starredsection}[1]{%
\OriginalSection*{#1}%
}

\newcommand\unstarredsection[2][]{%
\OriginalSection{#2}
}

\renewcommand{\section}{%
\@ifstar{\starredsection}{\unstarredsection}%
}%
\makeatother
```